# Password gets changed when updating User Model in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, passport.js, bcrypt

```
/**
* User.js
*
* @description :: TODO: You might write a short summary of how this model works and what it represents here.
* @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models
*/

var bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs');

function hashPassword(values, next) {
bcryptjs.hash(values.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    values.password = hash;
    next();
});
}

module.exports = {

connection: 'mysql',

attributes: {
        id:{
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        unique: true
        },
        displayname:{
        type: 'STRING',
        required: true
        },
        password:{
        type: 'STRING',
        required: true
        },

    // Override toJSON instance method to remove password value
    toJSON: function() {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        delete obj.password;
        return obj;
    },

},
// Lifecycle Callbacks
beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
    hashPassword(values, next);
},


beforeUpdate: function(values, next) {
    if (values.password) {
        hashPassword(values, next);
    }
    else {
        //IMPORTANT: The following is only needed when a BLANK password param gets submitted through a form. Otherwise, a next() call is enough.
        User.findOne(values.id).done(function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            }
            else {
                values.password = user.password;
                next();
            }
        });
    }
},


validPassword: function(password, user, cb) {
bcryptjs.compare(password, user.password, function(err, match) {
  if (err) cb(err);

  if (match) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(err);
  }
});
}

};
```

The hashPassword(values, next); in beforeUpdate method changes the password while changing any values of the user model though i don't send the password value in the 'param'. But it works fine when i change password for the user.

Example: When i change password for the current user, it should changed pass, hash it and stored in database. But i don't want the password to get changed (changes to random password) when i am updating other data in User Model.

***Edit: Working Now, Corrected Code:***
**Now, only if you send password: password in the Update method, it will update the password (hash and store) else it will only update the provided user fields.**

Controller(UserController.js):

```
updateDisplayName: function(req, res) {

var userid = req.token;
var newDisplayName = req.param('newdisplayname');

User.update({id: userid},{displayname: newDisplayName}).exec(function afterwards(err,updated){

if (err) {
res.json(err);
} else {
res.json("Success");
}
});

},
```

Model(User.js):

```
beforeUpdate: function(values, next) {
if(values.password) {
hashPassword(values, next);
} else {
next();
}
},
```

Comment: just check the hashPassword method is getting called in the beforeUpdate function

Comment: That is the issue but still trying to figure out how to resolve this.

Comment: Just put a console message for the value.password in beforeUpdate function and check what is the value of value.password

Comment: I tried console.log, it seems the old hashed password gets hashed again and stored in database. Making the old password not work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
beforeUpdate: function(values, next) {
if (values.password) {
    hashPassword(values, next);
}
```

This code has the problem that everytime a user model is updated(not password change) for eg: displayName is updated. Password in user model is already encrypted, it gets encrypted again and old password wont work no more.

Solution is to remove password attribute from user model before normal update(not change password). During password change, new password has to be set to user.password and update should be called.

Comment: I am not passing any password attribute when updating, i tried if (values.password !== null), but still gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the problem is that you get the password param passed even though you're not changing it. How about doing a bcrypt.compare on it when it arrives. If it's a match then do not re-hash the password. If it doesnt match it's considered a new password and you go ahead an hash it?

I am having this conundrum myself and I am going for this approach.